# Python Selenium can't execute a loop

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a code that extracts original movie titles from a website. The test version in which I input the titles manually seems to be working fine but when I try to create a loop that searches for titles from a list I run into some issues. This is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

films_test = ["Downton Abbey",
              "Squid Game"]

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,
                          service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

for film in films_test:
    driver.get("https://www.filmweb.pl/")
    driver.maximize_window()

    try:
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "didomi-notice-agree-button").click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/header/div[2]/div[2]").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        print("cookies closed")
    except:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
        print("no cookies popup")
        pass

    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/input')))
    search.send_keys(film)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/a/div[1]/span").click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    try:
        close_ad = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/span/span')))
        close_ad.click()
        print("ad closed")
    except:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
        print("ad closed automatically or didnt appear")
        pass

    dictionary = {}
    list_keys = []
    list_values = []

    if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'filmCoverSection__type').get_attribute("textContent") == "Serial":
        print("title is a series")
        for element in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'filmInfo__header'):
            key = element.get_attribute("textContent")
            list_keys.append(key)
            if "Sezon" in key:
                list_keys.remove(key)
                print("removed from key list")
            else:
                pass
        for element in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'filmInfo__info'):
            value = element.get_attribute("textContent")
            list_values.append(value)
            if "Sezon" in value:
                list_values.remove(value)
                print("removed from value list")
            else:
                pass
    else:
        print("title not a series")
        for element in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'filmInfo__header'):
            key = element.get_attribute("textContent")
            list_keys.append(key)
        for element in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'filmInfo__info'):
            value = element.get_attribute("textContent")
            list_values.append(value)

dictionary = dict(zip(list_keys, list_values))
print(dictionary)
org_title = dictionary['tytuł oryg.']
print(org_title)
```

The script extracts the original title for the first element on the list but fails to do so with the second one. This seems to be the problematic part:

```
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/input')))
    search.send_keys(film)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/a/div[1]/span").click()
```

As it returns the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kuban\PycharmProjects\baza_danych_filmowych\filmweb_lista.py", line 36, in <module>
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/input')))
  File "C:\Users\kuban\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00D75FD3+2187219]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D0E6D1+1763025]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C23E78+802424]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C51C10+990224]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C51EAB+990891]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C7EC92+1174674]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C6CBD4+1100756]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C7CFC2+1167298]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C6C9A6+1100198]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C46F80+946048]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C47E76+949878]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010190C2+2721218]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0100AAF0+2662384]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E0137A+526458]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E00416+522518]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D14EAB+1789611]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D197A8+1808296]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D19895+1808533]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D226C1+1844929]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76D46739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77D48FEF+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77D48FBD+1165]
```

The script also sometimes randomly stops working exactly at this part of the code even when searching for the first element on the list. Does anybody have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works (setup is for linux, however you can adapt it to your own setup). Given the kilometric xpaths you are using, I'm not sure where the exact issue is in your own code. You can change those xpaths like below. I suspect the issue comes from the fact the html in the page changes, so you need to re-initialize the variables for search:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/'

films_test = ["Downton Abbey",
              "Squid Game"]
browser.get(url)
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='didomi-notice-agree-button']"))).click()
    print('cookies accepted')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookies for you!') 
search_opener = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='searchOpener']")))
search_opener.click()
t.sleep(2)
search_input = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form__input form__input--empty']")))
for film in films_test:
    search_input.send_keys(film)
    first_search_result = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='resultsSection']/div[@class='resultItem']")))
    first_search_result.click()
    print(f'clicked the first result for film {film}')
    t.sleep(5)
    search_opener = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='searchOpener']")))
    search_opener.click()
    t.sleep(2)
    search_input = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form__input form__input--empty']")))

print('all done')
browser.quit()
```

The printout in the terminal:

```
cookies accepted
clicked the first result for film Downton Abbey
clicked the first result for film Squid Game
```